# removing punctuation then counting the no of every word occurance using python

Tags: python-2.7

Hello everybody I am new to python and need to write a program to eliminate punctuation then count the number of words in a string. So I have this:

```
import sys
import string
def removepun(txt):
    for punct in string.punctuation:
        txt = txt.replace(punct,"")
        print txt
        mywords = {}
        for i in range(len(txt)):
            item = txt[i]
            count = txt.count(item)
            mywords[item] = count
    return sorted(mywords.items(), key = lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
```

The problem is it returns back letters and counts them and not words as I hoped. Can you help me in this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> import string
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'One, two; three! four: five. six@#$,.!'
>>> occurrence = Counter(s.translate(None, string.punctuation).split())
>>> print occurrence
Counter({'six': 1, 'three': 1, 'two': 1, 'four': 1, 'five': 1, 'One': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

after removing the punctuation

```
numberOfWords = len(txt.split(" "))
```

Assuming one space between words

EDIT:

```
a={}
for w in txt.split(" "):
   if w in a:
     a[w] += 1
   else:
     a[w] = 1
```

how it works

1. a is set to be a dict
2. the words in txt are iterated
3. if there is an entry already for dict a[w] then add one to it
4. if there is no entry then set one up, initialized to 1

output is the same as Haidro's excellent answer, a dict with keys of the words and values of the count of each word

Comment: thank you for quick reply but i need to count every occurrence  of a word not total numbers