# Python treat words with commas the same as those without in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program, that reads a file and makes a dictionary, that shows how many times a word has been used:

```
filename = 'for_python.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    contents = file.read().split()
dict = {}
for word in contents:
    if word not in dict:
        dict[word] = 1
    else:
        dict[word] += 1
    
dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for i in dict:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

It works, but it treats words that have commas in them as different words, which I do not want it to do. Is there a simple and efficient way to do this?

Comment: You want to avoid ALL punctation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removing punctuation then counting the no of every word occurance using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266802/removing-punctuation-then-counting-the-no-of-every-word-occurance-using-python)

Answer (score 2):

Remove all commas before splitting them

```
filename = 'for_python.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    contents = file.read().replace(",", "").split()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you `strip()` with the different punctuation chars when using the `word`. Also don't use builtin `dict` name, its the dictionnary constructor

```
import string
words = {}
for word in contents:
    word = word.strip(string.punctuation)
    if word not in words:
        words[word] = 1
    else:
        words[word] += 1
```

---

For you know, it exists `collections.Counter` that does this jobs

```
import string
from collections import Counter

filename = 'test.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    contents = file.read().split()

words = Counter(word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in contents)

for k, v in words.most_common(): # All content, in occurence conut order descreasingly
    print(k, v)
for k, v in words.most_common(5): # Only 5 most occurrence
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: Note that this won't work good for something like `word1 word2,wrod3 word4`. The middle part will still be treated as `word2,word3`

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the whole data based on `" "` as the delimiter but not doing the same for commas. You can do so by splitting the words further using commas. Here's how:

```
...
for word in contents:
    new_words = word.split(',')
    for new_word in new_words:
        if new_word not in dict:
            dict[new_word] = 1
        else:
            dict[new_word] += 1
...
```